# override jqueryUI dialog buttons (save, cancel and etc to user's choice) text dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am passing some predefined values to jquery dialog but unable to pass buttons text. When user calls jquery dialog, he can be able give his own buttons text. For example: Save, cance, MyButton and etc.

```
var options = {
            autoOpen : true,
            dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx',
            draggable: false,
            height : 370,
            maxHeight : 600,
            maxWidth : 600,
            minHeight : 340,
            minWidth : 400,
            resizable : false, // also requires ui.resizable.js
            title: "Add New Address",
            modal: true,                
            width: 400,
            buttons: [{
                 text : "Yes Yes"
            }, {
                "cancel": "No"
            }]
        };
```

and calling dialog as shown below:

```
dialog1(options);
```

And dialog1 is looks like :`$("#dialog").dialog(options, {})`

Finally, the problem is how can I get the buttons text in dialog?

Update:

```
$("#dialog").dialog(options, {
        showTitlebar : true,

        buttons: {                    
            SAVE : function() {
                console.log($('.ui-button-text'));
                var add1 = $("#txtadd1").val();
                var add2 = $("#txtadd2").val();
                var landmark = $("#landmark").val();
                var city = $("#city").val();
                var pincode = $("#pincode").val();
                var state = $("#state").val();
                console.log(add1 + '  ' + add2 + '  ' + landmark + '  ' + city + '  ' + pincode + '  ' + state );
                var newModel = new Record();                        
                console.log(newModel);
                console.log(that.collection);
                console.log('Govindha Govindhaaaaaaaaaa');
                newModel.set({
                   add1 : add1,
                   add2 : add2,
                   landmark : landmark,
                   city : city,
                   pincode : pincode,
                   state : state
                });

                console.log(newModel);
                newModel.save({wait:true}, {
                    success : function(model, resp, options){
                        console.log('Model saved');
                        console.log(that.collection);

                        that.collection.add(resp[0]);
                        $(".elems").each(function(){
                            $(this).val('');
                        });
                        $(".errmsg").html('');
                        //console.log('Govindha Govindhaaaaaaaaaa');

                        $("#dialog").dialog('close');
                    },
                    error : function(model, xhr, options){
                        console.log("Something went wrong while saving the model");
                    }
                });   
            },
            CANCEL : function(){
                $(".elems").each(function(){
                    $(this).val('');
                });
                $(".errmsg").html('');
                $("#dialog").dialog('close');
            }
        },
        close: function(){
            $(".elems").each(function(){
                    $(this).val('');
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.each( $('#dialog').parent().find('.ui-button-text'), function(i, btn) {
    var label = options.buttons[i];
    btn.text(label);
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/6941/)

The basic idea is to iterate through each of the button-text in the dialog and get the text for the button from the options.buttons object and set it as the text for the button.
Depending on your DOM/Markup, you might require to tweak the code slightly to get it right. Please post your code/markup, in case you aren't able to get it fine. :)

Here's a function you can call to change any of the button-texts you want to update:

```
function changeBtnText(container, from, to) {
    var buttons = container.parent().find('.ui-button-text');
    $.each(buttons, function (i, btn) {
        if($(btn).text() == from) {
             $(btn).text(to);
             return false;
        }
    });
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
changeBtnText( $('#dialog'), 'Save', 'Dont Save' );
```

That will change the button whose text is 'Save' to 'Dont Save'.

Comment: Where should I write these lines? Please find the updated code in the question?

Comment: You can add the code anywhere After the call to $("#dialog").dialog(). Sorry for the delayed response. I just confirmed that it works.

Comment: Thank you for replay, but I am totally confused and unable to change the "SAVE" text button to "Yes Yes" of options object? Please help me!

Comment: Can you create a small demo of your code on jsfiddle.net . We don't have a sufficient enough insight into your code, as of now.

Comment: I've updated the code to change the button texts, every second. Refer to the dynamically_change_btn_text function to see how it's done. http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/6941/

Comment: @bakkupavan You're welcome. Did my answer help you out? If so, please remember to accept my answer and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

You should select the spans with the `ui-button-text` class, these are containing the dialog button labels. For finding their exact location in the DOM you should use the developer tools of the web browser. Though I guess if you make this selection:

```
$('.ui-button-text')
```

This will give the list (array) of the button texts in the order you have defined in the configuration object of your `dialog` method.